# Streambuilder is not displaying any data from firestore (Duplicate)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

i have a streambuilder to display grid of 3 image, is there something wrong with it? The output says "There is no task". when i print using these print(snapshot.data!.docs); it returns 0 in the debug console and the connection is waiting.

```
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _constructed = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('fotoupload')
      .orderBy("createdAt", descending: true)
      .snapshots();


Widget gridViewWidget(String docId, String img, String userImg, String name,
      DateTime date, String userId, int downloads) {
    return GridView.count(
      primary: false,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      crossAxisSpacing: 1,
      crossAxisCount: 1,
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            //createOwnerDetails
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Text(date.toString()),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            //createOwnerDetails
          },
          child: Image.network(
            img,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        Center(child: Text(userId)),
      ],
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return Image == null ? buildSplashScreen() : buildUploadForm();
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _constructed,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {

            print(snapshot.connectionState);
            print(snapshot.data!.docs);
            print(snapshot.data!.docs.length); // check all the data and connectionstate

            if (snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
              return GridView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return gridViewWidget(
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index].id,
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index]['Image'],
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index]['createdAt'].toDate(),
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index]['downloads'],
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index]['name'],
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index]['postid'],
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index]['userImage'],
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  'There is no tasks',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              );
            }
          }
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              'Something went wrong',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: Firebase Console]
[image: Debug Console]

i just want to display the data from firestore, is there something wrong from my streambuilder?

Comment: What makes you think the result you get is incorrect? In other words: can you show a screenshot of a document that you expect to be shown (from the Firebase console), that clearly shows that it meets the requirements of your code (so that it is in the right connect, has the field you order on)?

Comment: Thankyou sir for your reply, i inspected my code again and the requirements now is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if `connectionState` is `waiting`:

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
```

Then, checking if `active`

```
else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active)
```

Then, all the rest goes to `else`.

**New:**

Add another condition to check for `errors` from the beginning:

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }
```

Please note, that this part of your code can never be reached, given how you wrote it:

```
return Center(
            child: Text(
              'Something went wrong',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30),
            ),
```

**Other Error:**

There is a typo in the `'createAt '` field... is there a space at the end or no:

```
.orderBy("createAt", descending: true)
```

versus here:

```
snapshot.data!.docs[index]['createAt '].toDate(),
```

Comment: Sir Thankyou so much it works now !! but another problem occured about this line of code : snapshot.data!.docs[index]['createdAt'], and the error is type 'DateTime' is not a subtype of type 'String' or _TypeError (type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'String').

Comment: toDate() seems not work in my code

Comment: try this: (snapshot.data!.docs[index]['createdAt'] == null) ? null : (snapshot.data!.docs[index]['createdAt'] as Timestamp).toDate(),

Comment: I also answered your new post

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, appreciate it :)